# NPAPI plugin, winapi, notifyicon - disappears icon in tray after after a few hours

Tags: winapi, google-chrome, npapi

Written for Extension of chromium, it uses dll. In this dll used winapi.
ON WINAPI a window is to him an icon in the system tray.
When you initially start the expansion, the icon is displayed and everything works fine.
The problem is this, after a long period of time (several hours), the icon disappears, they have a place in the icon, and the icon itself is not.
This usually occurs when the computer is left overnight. In the morning you come, and no icon.
Restoring icons after sleep, as well as after a reboot explorer'a done.
Icon attached to the window created by CreateWindow.
Do not know what to think and where to dig.
I would appreciate any advice ...